# How to deploy Integrated Applet in a Web Application into Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, netbeans, applet

i've successfully integrated an applet (with an external jar) into a web applet and deployed locally with Netbeans that automatically runs Tomcat.
(i've followed [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html) tutorial , so in Netbeans i have 2 project: an applet project and a web application project that link that include the applet).

Now, how can put my web application (that link the applet) directly into a remote Tomcat?
I've seen my generated war but it doesn't include the applet jar and external library jar.

Answer (score 5):

For the web application, the jar of the applet is just a static file that must be served over HTTP by the app, just like a CSS, image, HTML or JS file. Just put the jar anywhere you want in the webapp tree (i.e. in the war file), but not under WEB-INF (which is not accessible from the outside).

Comment: How about external jars beside project jar? 
Where should we place it?